# Automatic load into Access from Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Please see code below, at the moment it loads data from the range "A1: G30000". I would like to alter this code so data from the range A1:D30000 and F1:G30000 is loaded, i.e. data from columnn F is excluded from the upload.

```
 strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xlsx")
 Do While Len(strFile) > 0
       strPathFile = strPath & strFile
       DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
             strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames = False, _
             "Data!A1:G30000,"
```

Comment: Change `A1:G30000` to `F1:G30000` in your code?

Comment: How would that enable the data from range a1:d30000 to be loaded

Comment: Why not load the whole sheet and further process in MS Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use:

```
"Data!A1:D30000;Data!F1:G30000"
```

or:

```
"Data!A1:D30000,Data!F1:G30000"
```

or open Excel and define a *Named Range* covering this compound range:

```
=Data!$A$1:$D$30000,Data!$F$1:$G$30000
```

Then reference the *name* you assign this Named Range in your code.